# How to listen to different layout buttons in one Java file?

Tags: android, button, listener, viewflipper

I am using view Flipper in Android,
how do you listen to different layout buttons in one class?

The code is:

```
<ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/myViewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <include android:id="@+id/firstLayout" layout="@layout/firstlayout"/>
        <include android:id="@+id/secondLayout" layout="@layout/secondlayout"/>
        <include android:id="@+id/thirdLayout" layout="@layout/thirdlayout" />`
 </ViewFlipper>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an android:onClick to your Button XML. Then you can list for that in your Activity.

Comment: Where are the buttons, by the way?

Comment: ya i can give android:onClick thank you its work.......

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply get your ViewFlipper like this:

```
ViewFlipper viewFlipper = findViewById(R.id.myViewFlipper);
```

Then just following this pattern :

```
View yourIncludedLayout1 = viewFlipper.findViewById(R.id.firstLayout);
Button yourButton = (Button)yourIncludedLayout1.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
```

Then set it to your clickListener which could be one for all buttons, or one for each button, but in one file, as you want